# Fantasy Isekai manga where mc has crafting skills

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The male mc is isekaied into a fantasy world with craft skills like woodworking. He uses his knowledge to help a bunny village build better walls and an iron pump. He also builds a pump for humans and teaches about hygiene in order to free other demihumans from being slaves to the humans. There is a chapter where he kills goblins and is found by human knights in a village which is damaged. I think it was a demihuman village and was taken over by humans. The goddess who transferred him appears quite a bit to talk to him as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Inaka no Home Center Otoko no Jiyuu na Isekai Seikatsu*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/inaka-no-home-center-otoko-no-jiyuu-na-isekai-seikatsu)

[image: Front cover of the manga]

> After a long day of labor, Masaru, who works for a rural home improvement store, sees his co-workers off and walks to his van. He never makes it, as he is immediately summoned to Alstatia by a frivilous goddess and her mother. They tell him that he's to be reincarnated in this strange land, and is given the chance to roll for special abilities. He pulls the lever of the mystical slot-machine before him, and manages to get a perfect skill set... for a carpenter, anyway. Now back on the ground and in the company of a race of bunny-people, Masaru decides to take his new life as it comes. Maybe get into manual labor again, build some houses, perhaps?

### Carpentry Skills

[image: Image showing his new skills] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

### Knights showing up after the goblin fight

[image] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

### Humans aren't aware of modern sanitation

[image] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

### He plans to free all the demihumans

[image] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Found with a search for `manga isekai crafting "bunny people"`

Comment: Incidentally, I got to where he taught the humans about sanitation and introduced pumps, but I was being too lazy to copy and paste more page images in. Plus, you've already accepted. :-D