# Isekai manga about a guy who is summoned to another world by a goddess and is saved by rabbit people who were kicked out of their former village

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, elves

Looking for an isekai manga about a guy who is summoned to another world by a goddess. He is saved by rabbit people who have been kicked out of their former village. He fortifies the village, builds them better houses, saves some elves, and the goddess wants him to go to the elf kingdom and destroy the creatures there. He meets the king and summons the goddess in front of him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what did the rabbit people save the MC from?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Could you be thinking of [*Inaka no Home Center Otoko no Jiyuu na Isekai Seikatsu*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/inaka-no-home-center-otoko-no-jiyuu-na-isekai-seikatsu)?

[image: Front cover of the manga]

> After a long day of labor, Masaru, who works for a rural home improvement store, sees his co-workers off and walks to his van. He never makes it, as he is immediately summoned to Alstatia by a frivilous goddess and her mother. They tell him that he's to be reincarnated in this strange land, and is given the chance to roll for special abilities. He pulls the lever of the mystical slot-machine before him, and manages to get a perfect skill set... for a carpenter, anyway. Now back on the ground and in the company of a race of bunny-people, Masaru decides to take his new life as it comes. Maybe get into manual labor again, build some houses, perhaps?

### Demihumans with bunny ears

[image: Image showing Masaru being embraced by a demihuman]

### Carpentry Skills

[image: Image showing his new skills] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

### Knights showing up after the goblin fight

[image] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

### Humans aren't aware of modern sanitation

[image] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

### He plans to free all the demihumans

[image] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

:) I'd provided the answer before at [Fantasy Isekai manga where mc has crafting skills](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268694/fantasy-isekai-manga-where-mc-has-crafting-skills/268696#268696)